# embedding excel files in wordpress page as iframe with elementor triggers a download and does not actuall display the file in the frame

Tags: wordpress, iframe, elementor, htmlwidgets

I'm trying to embed an excel file into a wordpress page and allow users to interact with it. I'm doing this via an iframe using elementor's html widget. The file does not display in the frame and instead when the page loads it triggers a download of the file.
Originally i was getting the file via an embed code from OneDrive live. This displayed the file contents, but the area of the file that was displayed was too large. I tried to use javascript to scale the contents being delivered to the iframe but was unable to do this because the content was not being served by the same host as my wordpress( at least that was my take-away from researching the issue).
I've been attempting to work around this issue. I created a new directory in my www/wordpress directory called excel_files and uploaded my file to it. I updated my iframe src to reflect this new location. Unfortunately the iframe does not display the file it simply downloads it when the page loads. I'v made what i believe are the appropriate adjustments to the relevant .conf files:

```
 location ~ \.xlsx$ {
        add_header Content-Disposition 'inline; filename="$uri"';
        types { application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet xlsx; }
    }
```

The problem still persists. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.